# How to add -aos to my 7zip batch file

Tags: windows, batch, zip, 7-zip

I will admit I am relatively new to using batch file for 7zip automation. I have searched extensively how to add the -aos to automatically skip matching files that have previously been extracted but I am coming up empty handed.

I am currently using a batch file that is working well. How can I add -aos?

```vb
@ECHO ON
SET source=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.zip"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"%%~pF\"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.7z"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"%%~pF\"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.rar"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"%%~pF\"
EXIT
```

Comment: What happens when you append `-aos` after `-o"%%~pF" ` ?

Comment: 7z.exe" x -aos "%%~fF"